# Having issue with substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to split the resolution something like below:

```
declare @t table (resolution nvarchar(100))

Insert into @t values ('1366 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
('1024 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
('640 X 480 @ 70 Hz')
```

I want the output as

```
Fst   |  Snd  | Thd  
------+-------+-----------
1366  |  768  |  60 Hz  
1024  |  768  |  60 Hz  
640   |  480  |  70 HZ
```

I have tried this query

```
select 
    *,
    substring(resolution, 1, charindex('X', resolution) - 1) as fst,
    substring(resolution, charindex('X', resolution) + 1, charindex('@', resolution) + 1) as snd
from 
    @t
```

But it is not returning the correct output.

Can anyone please show me what is wrong in here?

Comment: The third argument to [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the _length_, not the _end_ of the substring to be returned. `charindex('@', resolution) + 1` is not the length of the vertical resolution ('768').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
declare @t table (resolution nvarchar(100))

Insert into @t values ('1366 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
('1024 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
('640 X 480 @ 70 Hz');

SELECT LEFT(Resolution, CHARINDEX('X', Resolution) - 1) [1St],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, CHARINDEX('X', Resolution)+1, CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)-
       CHARINDEX('X', Resolution)-2) [2nd],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)+1, CHARINDEX('H', Resolution)-
       CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)-2) [3rd]
FROM @t;
```

**[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e1a91217dfaec9edeb74e76370688961)**

Or more better(without white spaces)

```
SELECT LEFT(Resolution, CHARINDEX('X', Resolution) - 2) [1St],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, 
                 CHARINDEX('X', Resolution)+2, 
                 CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)- CHARINDEX('X', Resolution)-3
                ) [2nd],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, 
                 CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)+2, 
                 CHARINDEX('H', Resolution) - CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)-3
                ) [3rd]
FROM @t
```

If you want `'Hz'` to be in the third column then

```
SELECT LEFT(Resolution, CHARINDEX('X', Resolution) - 2) [1St],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, 
                 CHARINDEX('X', Resolution)+2, 
                 CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)- CHARINDEX('X', Resolution)-3
                ) [2nd],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, 
                 CHARINDEX('@', Resolution)+2, 
                 LEN(Resolution)
                ) [3rd]
FROM @t;
```

Also, you could use **[`PARSENMAE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function (as [mkrabbani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3652345/mkRabbani) provide)to return both results as the following:

- With `'Hz'`

  ```
  SELECT Resolution,
         PARSENAME(Res, 3) Fst,
         PARSENAME(Res, 2) Snd,
         PARSENAME(Res, 1) Thd
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    ('1366 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
    ('1024 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
    ('640 X 480 @ 70 Hz')
  ) T(Resolution) 
  CROSS APPLY 
  (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(T.Resolution, ' X ', '.'), ' @ ', '.') Res
  ) TT;
  ```
- Without `'Hz'`:

  ```
  SELECT Resolution,
         PARSENAME(Res, 3) Fst,
         PARSENAME(Res, 2) Snd,
         PARSENAME(Res, 1) Thd
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    ('1366 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
    ('1024 X 768 @ 60 Hz'),
    ('640 X 480 @ 70 Hz')
  ) T(Resolution) 
  CROSS APPLY 
  (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(T.Resolution, ' X ', '.'), ' @ ', '.'), 'Hz', '') Res
  ) TT;
  ```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd6c308bfb49704dda8679b383fce8d2)** for the last 3 queries.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [`PARSENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function if there are only 3 part every time, and data format always as you shown.

```
SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution,' X ','.'),' @ ','.') ,3) Fst,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution,' X ','.'),' @ ','.') ,2) Snd,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution,' X ','.'),' @ ','.') ,1) Thd
FROM @t
```

Output is-

```
Fst     Snd     Thd
1366    768     60 Hz
1024    768     60 Hz
640     480     70 Hz
```

If you wants to exlude ' Hz' from the Thd column, Just do it-

```
SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution,' X ','.'),' @ ','.'),' Hz','') ,3) Fst,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution,' X ','.'),' @ ','.'),' Hz','')  ,2) Snd,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution,' X ','.'),' @ ','.'),' Hz','')  ,1) Thd
FROM @t
```

Comment: That will return `'Hz'` in the third column. Rethink and edit your answer.

Comment: @Sami nope, you can check the output I just added.

Comment: My bad didn't notice the desired results include `'Hz'` in the OP Q

Comment: Whats the issue? Hz is OP's requirement. Whats problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PARSENAME` function to split :

```
SELECT *,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(resolution,'@','.'),2),'X','.'),2) 'Fst' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(resolution,'@','.'),2),'X','.'),1) 'Snd' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(resolution,'@','.'),1) 'Thd'
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
select 
    *,
    substring(resolution, 1, charindex('X', resolution) - 1) as fst,
    substring(resolution, charindex('X', resolution) + 1, charindex('@', resolution) - charindex('X', resolution)-1) as snd ,
    substring(resolution, charindex('@', resolution) + 1,len(resolution) -  charindex('@', resolution)  ) as thr
from 
    @t
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner code using APPLY

```
SELECT LEFT(Resolution, idx1 - 2) [1St],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, idx1 + 2, idx2 - idx1 - 3) [2nd],
       SUBSTRING(Resolution, idx2 + 2, CHARINDEX('H', Resolution) - idx2 - 3) [3rd]
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY (
     SELECT CHARINDEX('X', Resolution) idx1
          , CHARINDEX('@', Resolution) idx2) i
```

Answer (score 1):

And since no string parsing post would be complete without an XML based solution:

```
SELECT ResXml.value(N'/x[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') As Fst,  
       ResXml.value(N'/x[2]', 'nvarchar(100)') As Snd, 
       ResXml.value(N'/x[3]', 'nvarchar(100)') As Thd
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(resolution, ' X ', '</x><x>'), ' @ ', '</x><x>') + '</x>' As Xml) As ResXml
    FROM @t
) As x
```